# SSH connection server

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, openssh

I'm new on ssh. I've more than one client and a server.
Client users are not a server users. Between client and server are only shared resources.
I'm trying to connect client users to server via ssh.
I created public and private keys. But when I try to login or when I try to copy key on server it replies "Permission denied, please try again."
I don't know if I can connect only with a registered user on the server or not.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use Putty and load the Key as part of the connection settings.  This is how I had to connect to the Amazon AWS servers.